# Decent satellite map for open source project?

Tags: mapbox, qml

I'm working on a cheap open source sidewalk travelling delivery robot.  I built a GUI using Qt/QML which (among other things) I use to view satellite data to identify and manually mark where sidewalks and crossings are. The manually constructed sidewalk map is then exported to a Spatialite database and used for high level navigation on the robot.

I using Mapbox for the imagery tiles right now.  It works pretty well for just me, but I would like to open source the GUI so everyone can use/improve it.  Catch is... How do I do that and make it easy to use without letting my Mapbox key into the wild and it potentially being used in something else?  Is there any other service I could use which has enough details to see sidewalks and crossings clearly (open/free would be great)?

I'm a GIS newbie, so any advice would be awesome!